# How to convert array of string values to escaped jSON Array in iOS?

Tags: json, swift, nsjsonserialization

For example:

```
let array = ["1234","5678"]
```

this array of values should be converted to the following string -

```
"[\"1234\",\"5678\"]"
```

Although I found answer here - [Objective-C - How to convert NSString to escaped JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843570/objective-c-how-to-convert-nsstring-to-escaped-json-string) but it doesn't look clean. Is there some cleaner way to do this ?

I am able to get this output - "["one","two"]" using

```
NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject
```

but how to have backslashes in between of strings?

Comment: @Eric Aya I am able to convert my array into strings i.e this output - "["one","two"]" , but how to add escaped characters ?

Comment: In the string `["one","two"]`, the `"`'s *are* characters which have been escaped (that's why they appear in the string itself, rather than delimiting separate strings). Try doing `print("[\"1234\",\"5678\"]")` – you'll get an output of `["one","two"]`. Now try doing `debugPrint("[\"1234\",\"5678\"]")` – Swift will insert backslashes into the output to show that the `"` characters are part of the actual string. You don't need to "add escaped characters".

Comment: @AjayKumar This is a common mistake: you don't need to do that unless your server is badly configured - and then you would have to fix the server, not to circumvent the issue from client side. // And don't forget that anyway you should send JSON **data** to a server, not a String in JSON format.